# How to zoom to d3.js svg overlay on google map

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I have a d3.js svg which I overlaid on Google map using OverlayView. Then a user specifies a zip code in an input text, and I need for my map to zoom in to that particular zip code. I have a latitude and longitude for the zip code. But I can't get it to zoom to the svg. I could zoom in using Google's API, but that's not what I need. I need to zoom in to the svg since there are data in there that needs to show in linear color. The following is my code so far:

```
function zoomtoZipCode(){
    var counties = d3.select("svg").select("g") //apply zoom here.
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 7])
        .on("zoom", zoom))
        .selectAll(".counties")
        .data(conus.features)
        .enter()
}
function zoom(){
    var p = d3.select("path")[0];
    d3.select(p).attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to define my zoom variable and use the terms in d3.js version 4 as follows:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", zoomed2);

        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "overlay")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(zoom);

        function zoomed2() {
            d3.select("#svgMap2").select("g").selectAll(".county")
                .text("text", function (d) { return d.properties.County; })
                .attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
                .select(".county").style("stroke-width", .5 / d3.event.transform.k + "px");
        }
```